# End the background process of php exec command

Tags: php, exec

Is there a way to end this background process executed by this code?

```
$process = exec('nohup java -jar '/selenium-server-standalone-3.8.0.jar -> /dev/null &');
```

I am simply running a jar file which is a server, I need to stop this server after some code is executed, is there a way to end it? something like

```
end($process);
die($process);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To launch your background process, use a command like this:

```
exec('nohup java jar "/selenium-server-standalone-3.8.0.jar" > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!', $pid);
```

This is redirecting stdout to /dev/null, and then stderr to stdout so that the process can actually continue in the background. After that, it is returning the processid of the new background process and saving it in $pid.

Then, later, you can stop it with `exec('kill '.$pid);`